# Swift animate height anchor animation not working as expected

Tags: ios, swift

Here I'm trying to updated height anchor of a button 100 to 300 and 300 to 100, like expand and collapse. I know we can create  `var constraint: NSLayoutConstraint` and updated. But In my case I have UIStackView contains multiple buttons based on server configuration. So I can't create `NSLayoutConstraint` explicitly.

So, I want to update the constraint on click of a button. Below I'm adding my code.
Help is greatly appreciated.

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let button = UIButton()
        self.view.addSubview(button)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
       
        button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
        button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector (onButtonAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    }
    
    @objc func onButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        sender.heightAnchorConstrint?.constant = sender.heightAnchorConstrint!.constant == 100 ? 300 : 100
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }


extension UIView {
    var heightAnchorConstrint: NSLayoutConstraint? {
        return constraints.first { $0.firstAnchor == heightAnchor }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: not animating 100 to 300 on first click .. 300 to 100 on second click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in finding constraint in `UIView` extension.

Change your extension with this

```
extension UIButton {
    var heightAnchorConstrint: NSLayoutConstraint? {
        return self.constraints.last(where: { ($0.firstItem as? UIButton == self && $0.firstAttribute == .height) })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, did observed one thing? Actually button increasing height and changing top anchor also. It should be in same place from top and should grow towards bottom only. Hope you got my point.

Comment: But yes, we have to change only one constraint.         ```swift button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true ```

Answer (score 0):

this is the correct code without extensions:
declare your button an the different height variable

```
let button = UIButton()

var onehundred: NSLayoutConstraint?
var threehundred: NSLayoutConstraint?

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        
    view.addSubview(button)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector (onButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    
    button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
    button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
    onehundred = button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
    onehundred?.isActive = true // activate only the first height
    threehundred = button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300)
    button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    
}
```

now call your func to animate button:

```
var hundred = 1 // set var for height button control
    
@objc func onButtonAction() {
    if hundred == 1 {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
            self.onehundred?.isActive = false
            self.threehundred?.isActive = true
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.hundred = 0
        }
    } else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
            self.threehundred?.isActive = false
            self.onehundred?.isActive = true
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.hundred = 1
        }
    }
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: You can optimize button action by this. ```{
        self.onehundred?.isActive.toggle()
        self.threehundred?.isActive.toggle()
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }```

Comment: @RajaKishan Yes you're right, but I want to show him the basic code for the right developer way. After he learn the basic, he can work with toggle() and extensions...